# Problem with GeoServer modifying a style when uploading an SLD via the REST API

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, sld, geoserver-rest-api

I have an SLD called `my_data.sld` (created in QGIS 3.2.x) with looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>my_data</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>my_data</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e15989</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

If I upload SLD file via the GeoServer control panel, then apply it to a layer, the layer is correctly styled, no problem.

However, I want to add upload this style to a workspace and apply it via the rest API, which I do via these commands (following the [curl examples](https://geoserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest/examples/curl.html#creating-a-layer-style)):

```
curl -v -u admin:pass -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<style><name>my_data</name><filename>my_data.sld</filename></style>" https://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_workspace/styles
curl -v -u admin:pass -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml" -d @/home/sam/my_data.sld https://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_workspace/styles/my_data
```

Both commands appear to work giving `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK` codes. I have the new style in my workspace but there's a problem with the content of the style. Inspecting the new style in the GeoServer Style Editor control panel shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>my_data</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>my_data</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Single symbol</sld:Name>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill/>
                <sld:Stroke/>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>7</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Clearly tags with se:SvgParameter have not been translated into whatever format the style is in now.

I've tried to modify the `<StyledLayerDescriptor>` to match the manual upload that worked, without success.

I thought the issue might be related to the  `"Content-type:application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml"` but can't find an appropriate content type either.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing an SLD 1.1.0 file (or **S**ymbology **E**ncoding) with the SLD 1.0.0 format so GeoServer is filtering out the 1.1.0 elements to make it compliant with 1.0.0. You need to set the content-type to `application/vnd.ogc.se+xml` as is documented in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/styles.html) though it would help if QGis made it clearer that it was exporting SE not SLD.

Comment: A style exported from QGIS using the "style", "save as" functionality in the style editor begins with "<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.1.0" ", so it's clear it's SE. Not sure how the style above got "exported"?

Comment: You are quite right, it's there in the manual, I didn't put it together though :)

Comment: @AndreaAime hi, thanks for commenting. To clarify, I exported the above pasted style from qgis 3.2.0-bonn via the "Symbology" Properties window, then "Style"-->"Save Style", then selecting "SLD File" option. Hope that's useful.

Comment: Doh right, I mixed up the two styles in the question, the one exported by QGIS states "1.1.0"